# What is better for you - a whole wheat piece of toast or a scooped out whole wheat bagel?

Tags: health, nutrition-information

I was having a debate with someone around this on which is healthier having egg whites on:

- A piece of whole wheat toast
- A [scooped out](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcQEfooXGBkZRRj4z6uQrvzhBB1XRtYuVdfhm36ya0M0fM_aEi_z) whole wheat bagel

I thought the toast was still much healthier still but couldn't find anything to back it up.  There are a lot of [bagel versus bread articles](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/bagels-vs-bread-9332.html) out there but none factoring the value of the scooped out bagel.

Answer (score 1):

The scooped out bagel is the dumbest thing I've ever seen (Why not just cut it in half again instead of scooping out the middle? Are you stuffing it with something after scooping it out?). People are way too concerned with the *amount* of calories they are eating when they should be concerned about the *type* of calories they are eating.

If you're concerned about too many calories, then you've reduced some by scooping out the middle of the bagel. But the quality of the nutrients in either the toast or the bagel (which is "healthier") has nothing to do with the quantity.

**Compare the ingredients in both if you want to know which is healthier.**